# Regex with little complex situation (If- Else)

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

My pattern is going to be

```
'@' + '6 char' + '2 numeric' + 'optional value on the basis of numeric value' + '3 char'
```

Consider below for optional values

```
if  '01'     then     '6 char hexa decimal'
if  '02'     then     '1 char hexa decimal'
if  'other'  then     NO VALUE
```

So Possible value could be:

```
@DEEPAK0100FFBASHA      when i break (@ DEEPAK 01 00FFBA SHA)
@DEEPAK02AXYZ           when i break (@ DEEPAK 02 A      XYZ)
@SHARMA99XYZ            when i break (@ SHARMA 99        XYZ)
```

How to write the regex to get it to break the given string correspondingly?

Comment: if  'other'` , other means? two digit number?

Comment: yes... other mean 2 digit in if condition.. for 01/02 we have such condition, for other 2 digits no optional values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the below anchored regex.

```
@"^@[A-Z]{6}(?:01[\dA-F]{6}|02[\dA-F]|(?:(?!0[12])\d){2})[A-Z]{3}$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vS3oX1/2)

Comment: sorry man... but its validating for below as well. @DEEPAK01SHA---
@DEEPAK02XYZ---@SHARMA99XYZ.  notice for 01/02  I removed the optional value and it is still validating

Comment: Thanks Avinash.. :) I really appreciate you quick response and fix. (y)  Can you please post a link if you have any for lookhead.  I am weak in it.. :(

Comment: hahaha google's first link.. ;)  i dunno why but i find this site really un-understandable.. well thanks man for you response..